# How bitmasks are check in fd_set used in select?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

According to this article [poll vs select vs event-based](http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/poll-vs-select.html):

> select() only uses (at maximum) three bits of data per file
>   descriptor, while poll() typically uses 64 bits per file descriptor.
>   In each syscall invoke poll() thus needs to copy a lot more over to
>   kernel space. A small win for select().

Here is the implementation of fd_set (found on [Advisories : multiple applications fd_set structure bitmap array index overflow](http://securityvulns.com/advisories/sockets.asp)

```
#ifndef FD_SETSIZE
#define FD_SETSIZE  1024
#endif
#define NBBY    8       /* number of bits in a byte */
typedef long    fd_mask;
#define NFDBITS (sizeof (fd_mask) * NBBY)   /* bits per mask */
#define howmany(x,y)    (((x)+((y)-1))/(y))
typedef struct _types_fd_set {
    fd_mask fds_bits[howmany(FD_SETSIZE, NFDBITS)];
} _types_fd_set;

#define fd_set _types_fd_set
```

So, in the end, fd_set is just an array of `long`. It is also written:

> A call to FD_SET sets a bit to 1 using socket number as an index:

which means, if I got a socket fd number 5, the element indexed 5 will be seleted, and its first bit will be flipped from 0 to 1. Since `select()` uses 3 bits, I guess the other two bits are for sending and receive. Is this correct? Why does `select()` use a long when it only needs 3 bits?

Also, stated above, `poll()` uses 64 bits for checking. Why does `poll` need to check every bit in `pollfd` struct? Here is the `pollfd` struct:

```
struct pollfd {
    int fd;         // the socket descriptor
    short events;   // bitmap of events we're interested in
    short revents;  // when poll() returns, bitmap of events that occurred
};
```

The total bits in the struct is 64 bits, for a 32-bit int and two 16-bit short. I know the usual way of checking a bit flag is using `AND (&)` operator to filter out other irrelevant bits. Does that apply to this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't use 1 `long` per se. It uses a bit field of `FD_SETSIZE` bits, in this case 32 32 bits longs or 16 64 bits longs. By using longs, it allows to use less memory operations on 64 bit machines (which are widespread on Unix already for 20 years). They could have used normal `int` but then they wouldn't have had an advantage on 64 bit machines. It's only forward thinking.

If you used select on several file descriptors you need the room for all the file descriptors. Imagine you want to read from 3 sockets, from a SCSI device and a file and the file descriptor values are respectively  3, 7, 10, 12 and 67, how would you represent that? Use a bitset where the bit with that number is set.

```
 00010001.00101000:00000000.00000000:00000000.00000000:00000000.00000000   00010000.00000000
    ^   ^   ^ ^                                                               ^
    0   0   1 1                                                               6 
    3   7   0 2                                                               7
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer verified my comment in `unwind` post. Now i get how sockets associate in `fd_set`. Array of 32 elements means 1024 bits for the limit of 1024 file descriptors (defined by `FD_SETSIZE`). As for poll, it uses a whole struct for just a socket descriptor. However, I think that approach is easier to understand than having to thinking in bit.

Comment: Yes, it depends on how many descriptors you have to check (I once wrote a terminal muxer that could manage 112 SCSI communication devices plus a dynamic number of sockets with listen fd's and read/write. Managing that with `poll` would have resulted in a lot of memory copies.

Answer (score 5):

> poll() typically uses 64 bits per file descriptor. In each syscall invoke poll() thus needs to copy a lot more over to kernel space. A small win for select().

Fallacy -- if you only want to monitor one fd, poll(2) will get you away with those 64 bits, while for select(), you have to copy up to like 12288 bits (3 sets, each 4096 bits usually).

Also, poll() supports *fd* with a value larger than FD_SETSIZE.

Answer (score 4):

The reason `select()` uses `long`s is to encode *many* bits into a single variable value. A `long` can hold 32 (or sometimes 64, these days) bits typically, which means you can represent a 32-file set using a single value of type `long`.

The "three bits per file" comes from the three different `fd_set` values you typically use in order to select for both read, write and exceptions. Three `long` values is (assuming a 32-bit `long`), 32 * 3 = 96 bits, but can select for all three conditions for 32 different files, thus spending 3 bits per file. This assumes you `select()` for each of those 32 files in all three sets, which I think is at least somewhat rare.

Since `poll` represents file descriptors directly using an `int`-sized field, rather than implicitly by index into a bit set, it uses more space.

Basically, `select()`'s design takes advantage of the assumption that file descriptors are * small* integers, and that they're allocated from 0 and up.

Comment: I see. 3 bits per each socket descriptor, each bit resides on each `fd_set`. Typically a bit is a file in `select()`, with is switched from 0 to 1 depend on the `fd_set` context (if a socket requests a reading, thus the bit represents that socket will be flipped in `fd_set` which is used for reading. Meanwhile. `poll` will have to use the whole integer just for a file descriptor.)